# Adding icons from the right or left to menu H2 or Li

Tags: routes

[image]

Let's say I want to add Icons from the right\left of a Drupal menu H2 or li (such as in the place in the picture)... Actually I would also like to put a picture as a menu item by itself...

What is a good, veteran, and trusted module you could recommend for achieving all of these targets?

Thanks.

Comment: Special menu item module ... or menu image module. Im on my phone...

Answer (score 0):

What a coincidence. I made good use of this module today because I needed to have bolded text in my menu items:

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_html

After enabling you'll get a checkbox on each menu item that allows you to add HTML to the menu title (anything inside the anchor essentially). So this is where you would put your `<img>` tag or the markup necessary for your icons.

Note for security, make sure *only trusted users* have the ability to use this option, as you can imagine it creates an opportunity to embed malicious code.

EDIT: OP asked how you might add icons using this technique. I would use an icon font. For example with [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) you can put in some markup like `<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>` and it will  use CSS to display the icon there. Font Awesome covers most bases. If you can't find something specific try [icoMoon](https://icomoon.io/app) or [Fontastic](http://fontastic.me/).

It's really up to you how you implement this. See the other poster's answer for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: I've installed the module but I didn't see a way to add Icon-Only Menu-item... I wonder what's your way to do that? Ben.

Comment: Read my answer again, I never said there was an option for 'Icon-Only Menu-item'. This module gives you the ability to add any HTML or markup you want (which includes images, tags that generate icons, etc.). If you want to stick with a pure CSS solution, you can use the menu attributes module to generate icons as a background image on the list item, as @malcomio suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar using the [Menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module

This allows CMS users to add a class to a menu item.

Then certain classes in the theme CSS are set to have a background image, with text hidden, or an image in the :before or :after pseudo-element.